# Por que o plural da palavra "qualquer" ocorre no meio do termo?

Tags: verbos, pronomes, número-gramatical

Ao passar um termo que está no singular para o plural, é normal que modifiquemos a desinência dele.

**Exemplos:**

> Bombo**m** = Bombo**ns**
> Cana**l** = Cana**is**
> Troféu = Troféu**s**
> Amor = Amor**es**
> Dor = Dor**es**
> Mês = Mes**es**
> Ovo = Ovo**s**

No entanto, o plural da palavra **qua*l*quer** ocorre no meio dela: **qua*is*quer**.

- Por que o plural de *qualquer* ocorre no meio da palavra?
- Há outras palavras em que o plural ocorre no meio delas?

Comment: Eu não diria sufixo, diria "fim".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Qualquer* é uma [conhecida](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/quaisquer/733) exceção à regra da formação do plural.

Isso se deve ao fato dela ser uma justaposição de "qual" (pl. *quais*) e do *verbo* (que portanto não é pluralizado) *querer* na terceira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo.

Outras palavras com "plural no meio delas" (ou quase, já que são separadas por hífen) são alguns dos assim chamados *substantivos compostos [não-sintagmáticos](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/pc/comps_construcao.htm#naoSintagmatico)*, como, [por exemplo](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/pc/comps_flexao.htm):

> "anos-luz", "palavras-chave", "operárias-padrão", "salários-família", "garotas-propaganda", "guerras-relâmpago", "joões-ninguém" .